# Usercontrol event firing multiple times asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following code: -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Testing.Event_Delegate
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        WebUserControl2 QT2;
        WebUserControl3 QT3;
        DataTable dtQuestionSet;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtQuestionSet = (DataTable)Session["DataTableW"];
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack == false)
            {
                Session["Counter"] = 0;
                Session["QuestionCount"] = 0;
                Session["CompletedInsp"] = false;
            }

            //check to see if the inspection process is complete and display pass\fail and log. Else carry on.
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["CompletedInsp"]) == true)
            {
                //Response.Write("Failed");
                ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                return;
            }

            // all controls need to be rendered every page postback otherwise the rest of the code loses scope.
            QT2 = (WebUserControl2)this.LoadControl("WebUserControl2.ascx");
            UC2BtnClickEvent.MyEvent2 += new UC2BtnClickEvent.OnMyEvent2(ChecKResult);
            QT3 = (WebUserControl3)this.LoadControl("WebUserControl3.ascx");
            UC2BtnClickEvent.MyEvent3 += new UC2BtnClickEvent.OnMyEvent3(ChecKResult);
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(QT2);
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(QT3);

            QT2.Visible = false;
            QT3.Visible = false;

            if (IsPostBack == false)
            {

                dtQuestionSet = new DataTable();
                MakeDataTabledtQuestionSet();

            }
            else
            {
                dtQuestionSet = (DataTable)Session["DataTableW"];
            }
            Session["DataTableW"] = dtQuestionSet;
        }

        void ChecKResult(object sender, EventArgs e, string strTextBox, string strMyDescription)
        {
            Label1.Text = "You Answered: - " + strMyDescription;



            if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) > Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCount"]))
            {
                Session["CompletedInsp"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //carry on with inspection
                Session["Counter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) + 1;
                dtQuestionSet = (DataTable)Session["DataTableW"];
                RunInspection();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
        }

        protected void cmdStartInspection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Counter"] = 0;
            GetQuestions();
        }

        protected void GetQuestions()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PromptedInspConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test.GetQuestions", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Block1", cmbBlock1.Text));

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DataRow drQuestions = dtQuestionSet.NewRow();
                drQuestions["QuestionText"] = dr[1].ToString();
                drQuestions["ExpectedResponse"] = dr[2].ToString();
                drQuestions["QuestionType"] = dr[3].ToString();
                dtQuestionSet.Rows.Add(drQuestions);
            }
            Session["DataTableW"] = dtQuestionSet;
            Session["QuestionCount"] = dtQuestionSet.Rows.Count;

            conn.Close();

            RunInspection();
        }

        protected void RunInspection()
        {
            switch (dtQuestionSet.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"])][2].ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    QT2.QuestionText = dtQuestionSet.Rows[0][0].ToString();//"I'm asking a question 1";
                    QT2.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "2":

                    QT3.QuestionText = dtQuestionSet.Rows[0][0].ToString();//"I'm asking a question 2";
                    QT3.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void MakeDataTabledtQuestionSet()
        {
            dtQuestionSet.Columns.Add("QuestionText");
            dtQuestionSet.Columns.Add("ExpectedResponse");
            dtQuestionSet.Columns.Add("QuestionType");

        }

    }
}
```

When I click on the button on a usercontrol with the code: -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Testing.Event_Delegate
{
    public partial class WebUserControl2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        string questionAsked;

        public string QuestionText
        {
            set { questionAsked = value; }
            get { return questionAsked; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = QuestionText;
            TextBox1.Focus();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UC2BtnClickEvent bEvent = new UC2BtnClickEvent();
            bEvent.onRefresh2Event3(sender, e, TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Text );
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

It runs the procedure `CheckResults` 3 times on the aspx page when I only need it to run once.

UC2BtnClickEvent.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Testing.Event_Delegate
    {
        public class UC2BtnClickEvent
        {
            public delegate void OnMyEvent2(object sender, EventArgs e, string strTextBox, string strMyDescription);
            public static event OnMyEvent2 MyEvent2;

            public virtual void onRefresh2Event2(object sender, EventArgs e, string strTextBox, string strMyDescription)
            {
                if (MyEvent2 != null)
                {
                    MyEvent2(sender, e, strTextBox, strMyDescription);
                }

            }

            public delegate void OnMyEvent3(object sender, EventArgs e, string strTextBox, string strMyDescription);
            public static event OnMyEvent3 MyEvent3;

            public virtual void onRefresh2Event3(object sender, EventArgs e, string strTextBox, string strMyDescription)
            {
                if (MyEvent3 != null)
                {
                    MyEvent3(sender, e, strTextBox, strMyDescription);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

What have I done wrong to make this happen please as it should only run once.

Comment: On the `Page_Load` event it will get called twice. What does `UC2BtnClickEvent` look like? I'm guessing the third one is from there.

Comment: Hi @Louis I've added the code above. I don't know if it's relevant but there would have been 1 page_load and 2 Postbacks happen before clicking the button on the usercontrol. Not sure if that's relevant lol.

Comment: Me just being curious: what are you trying to do????

Comment: I might be going down the wrong route. Basically we have a list of questions that is received from a stored procedure. I then go through row by row asking the relevant question. There are 2 question types. A yes/no type and a input box type. Depending on the question I want to display, 2 different user controls which are the 2 different question types. When the user either presses yes/no or enters text into the text box I want it to check the answer and then move onto the next question. Hope that makes sense. I was looking at user controls to add new question types in the future.